# Error while importing font or images file inside scss using Webpack 4 and react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I am using webpack and react js.
I am getting this error when i try to import image or font file inside my scss file.

I have tried many solutions but none of them solved my problem,

webpack.common.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuHdS.jpg)

```
const path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js",
    vendor: "./src/vendor.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "imgs"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Here is another webpack.dev.js

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/template.html"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", //3. Inject styles into DOM
          "css-loader", //2. Turns css into commonjs
          "sass-loader" //1. Turns sass into css
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

ERROR in ./src/assets/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/assets/index.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../src/assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf' in 'C:\Users\jamal\Documents\webpack-demo-app\src\assets'
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

Comment: Do you maybe have a folder around the font file?

Comment: Yes, my fonts are inside a folder.

Comment: I meant to ask maybe it is in a nested folder so the folder structure isn't correct?

Comment: I am unable to add image here so i have added in drive so you can clearly see my folder structure https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f5n9JSR1a3NNt2v7ng4pAf7XOpO5-VHy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post an image with the fonts folder opened?

Comment: here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9i2jd8ZgavYRVWUYQc3XXQNu6sil2CN/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that the import actually takes "place" from the root index.scss file (the one that loads all the other partials). So the path you are using to fetch the asset is not accurate.

You need to use `./fonts/icomoon.ttf` instead of `../fonts/icomoon.ttf`

your file structure:

```
assets/
------/fonts
------/images
------/sass
------/---/partial1.scss // while the reference to the image is here
------/index.scss        // the actual root of the reference call is here
```

Comment: Thank you, I am able to solve the issue as per your suggestions.